# how to set page icon to Jfilechooser dialog

Tags: java, swing, awt

i am going to create an applet jar which has a JFileChooser open dialog. and i want to change its icon.

```
frame = parentFrame;
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("com/biztree/docmntui/client/applet/favicon.gif");
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

and then

```
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
```

it works fine when i run it as applet.
but when i trying to run it in GWT web page its shows java default icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new ImageIcon("com/biztree/docmntui/client/applet/favicon.gif");
```

The `String` based constructor for an `ImageIcon` interprets the string as a `File` path.  I doubt that would work with GWT.  It is probably expecting to deal with the resource by `URL`.  To get an URL, do something like:

```
URL favIconUrl = 
    this.getResource("com/biztree/docmntui/client/applet/favicon.gif");
```

Use the `URL` instead of the `String` in the `ImageIcon` constructor.